# How to configure app.yaml in Google Cloud to handle like a normal web server when using PHP?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

The default on google cloud APP Engine is to have any request handle by ONE file.

So 
http://mysite/page1.php  will go to http://mysite/index.php
and
http://mysite/page2.php  will ALSO go to http://mysite/index.php

This is extremely annoying.  How can I configure app.yaml  so that if I want to go to 
http://mysite/page2.php   I get page2.php AND NOT index.php??

Thank you

Comment: What is your `app.yaml` file content?

Comment: handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto

Answer (score 0):

You can configure multiple handlers as described in the [app.yaml handlers documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element). App engine by default does not expose every file in your application to receive HTTP requests and requires that you configure the ones you want to handle requests.

Comment: But how?  My app.yaml is this handlers(php 72)
- url: /.*
  script: auto